# Is there a green arrow in for check in?

Tags: check-in

I am using SharePoint 2013. I know that there is a green down arrow for a document that is checked out. My question is, does SharePoint 2013 have a green up arrow for a document that has been checked in? I do not see it on my document, but only from the ribbon bar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such arrow exist for the Checked In documents. Basically the behavior is like this.

1. If the document is checked-Out then you will see the down arrow (green) to tells you about it status.
2. If the there is no green arrow then its mean the document is checked in. this is default behavior.

but if you want, you can write your own code to make this happen.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no checked in arrow. The absence of an arrow indicates it is checked in.